# Why is my Required message show before submit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this controller for create new customer type. Code works, it creates new customer, send error, if user create same customer twice.

But the problem is, that in the beginning (when user came to form) it already alerts that my field is required! I want to show required after submit (if is input field empty).

My model is:

```
public class CustomerType
{
    public int IdNewType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer is required!")]
    public string CustomType { get; set; }

}
```

And controller is:

```
public ActionResult CreateNewCustomerType(Models.CustomerType customerType)
{
try
{
  using (var dataC = new userDbEntities())
  {
     var sysCustomerType = dataC.CustomTypes.Create();

     if (sysCustomerType != null)
     {
        sysCustomerType.CustomerType = customerType.CustomType;

        var count = dataC.CustomTypes.Count(c => c.CustomerType == customerType.CustomType);
        if (count == 0)
        {
           dataC.CustomTypes.Add(sysCustomerType);
           dataC.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("CustomerTypeView", "LoginAdmin");
         }
         else
         {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomType", "This customer alerady exists!");
         }
      }
      else
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError("CustomType", "");
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   string error = ex.Message;
}
return View(customerType);
}
```

And in View I use this for showing errors:

```
@model AdminRole.Models.CustomerType
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()  
    <label class="control-label" for="us">Stranka</label>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdNewType)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.CustomType, new{@class="form-control", id="us"})

    <span>@Html.ValidationSummary(false, null, new{@class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible", role="alert"})</span>

        <input class="btn btn-default pull-left btn-success" type="submit" value="Create"/>

}
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Can you please show both the GET and POST action on your controller? :)

Comment: wait @Tobias, this is my whole controller for this part... Shoud I have something more... This is simple create form, Do you need get and post?

Comment: It seems @Tobias that I needed Post and Get for my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ActionResult CreateNewCustomerType()
{
    return view();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNewCustomerType(Models.CustomerType customerType)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Try it like this.  I think this will solve your problem.